# Getting Keras and tensorflow via Anaconda

Tags: windows-8, installation, python, anaconda

I have an old Windows8 and I have great troubles getting Keras and tensorflow with Anaconda. I

```
conda create -n ml python=3.6.5
conda activate ml
conda install pip
```

I had to run the last line otherwise my pip wouldn't work. Lastly I run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

and get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt
```

The answers from here couldn't help me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46854451/pip-install-r-requirements-txt-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-requiremen

Is there any I can physically find the file and place it in the right path? and what is the right path?

I use the newest version of anaconda and python 3.6.5